# Which mining pools do not require account creation?

Tags: mining-pools

I know Eligius doesn't have a lengthly setup process, you just use your payout address as the username.

Which other pools are this easy to start with?

Answer (score 3):

You can try http://p2pool.info/

And P2Pool.info does not keep fees, they redistribute it ;)

In general you don't have to subscribe to P2P Pool (just search for "p2p bitcoin pool").

Comment: This requires me to run extra software, right?

Comment: Indeed, according to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool#Joining_the_pool you have to launch p2pool binary and just use your common miner software on 127.0.0.1:9332

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm going to iterate over [this list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_mining_pools). Although I think it is not very clear what "account creation" would imply, I list the ones that just want your Bitcoin address.

Ones I found that **do not require account creation**:

- [**50 BTC**](https://50btc.com/)
- [**Eligius**](http://eligius.st/~gateway/)
- [**Horrible Horrendous Terrible Tremendous Mining Pool**](http://hhtt.1209k.com/)
- [**P2Pool**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool)
- [**BitParking**](http://mmpool.bitparking.com/register) (requires you to create a UserId, but no password or whatever so basically you can just enter randomness and a Bitcoin address)

And ones that do:

- [ABCPool.co](http://www.abcpool.co/)
- [BitClockers](http://bitclockers.com/)
- [Slush's pool](https://mining.bitcoin.cz)
- [BitMinter](https://bitminter.com/)
- [BTC Guild](https://www.btcguild.com/)
- [BTC Oxygen](http://btcoxygen.com/)
- [BTCMine.com](http://btcmine.com/)
- [btcmp.com](http://www.btcmp.com/)
- [BTCWarp](http://www.btcwarp.com/)
- [CoinLab's protected pool](http://pool.coinlab.com/partners/protected/sign-in)
- [DeepBit](http://deepbit.net/)
- [Eclipse Mining Pool](https://eclipsemc.com/)
- [MaxBTC](https://www.maxbtc.com/)
- [Ozcoin](https://ozcoin.net/)
- [Polmine](https://polmine.pl/)
- [pool.itzod.ru](https://pool.itzod.ru/register)
- [TripleMining](https://www.triplemining.com/)

Answer (score 1):

50BTC, but I'm pretty sure they take some fees, while Eligius is takes transaction fees instead.

Comment: Eligius does keep transaction fees.  I think it would be deceptive to describe it as "100% free".